# Dynamical slug on custom post type

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm trying to custom urls of my custom post type.
I want to preprend a taxonomy term before the post name.

I create my post type with :

```
 $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Event', 'test' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'thumbnail', 'title', 'editor' ),
        'taxonomies'          => array(),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 20,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-tickets-alt',
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => '%univers%',
            'with_front' => false,
        ),``
    );

    register_post_type( 'event', $args );
```

And i replace the %univers% with what i want :

```
function test_show_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'event' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'univers' );
        if( $terms ){
             return str_replace( '%univers%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }else{
             return str_replace( '%univers%' , '' , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
 }
 add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'test_show_permalinks', 12, 2 );
```

It's works fine with my post type but broke all my other pages (404).

Anybody have any idea where that might have come from?

Thanks.

Comment: Try saving Permalinks once, that might work

Comment: Hello,  i tried but It doesn't work.

Comment: You have two different post types with the same url pattern, one will always win over the other. This is why custom post types are prefixed with a unique slug by default.